# Rotate a 3d Array

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures

I have a 3D array represented by a `int[,,]`. I want to be able to rotate it by 90 (or -90) degrees increment on any of the 3 axis.

#### Example

For the following 2D array:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I would expect this result:

```
4 1
5 2
6 3
```

I want this same logic, but applicable for 3D arrays.

Comment: These seem to be for 2d arrays. I am looking for rotation of a 3d array.

Comment: So I would get the cross sections of the array, apply the transformations, and then  reshape the array from the cross sections?

Comment: 3 *3 seems 2d to me. I am sorry if I do not understand matrices correctly, but wouldn't 3 * 3 * 3 be 3d?

Comment: How do you represent your 3d matrix in actual code? `int[][][]`? `int[,,]`?

Comment: yes, int [,,]. I am using C#. I wish I had Numpy in C#! I think that would rotate it.

Comment: Ok, do all of the dimensions have the same size (like [10,10,10]) or they can have different sizes (like [10,5,26])?

Comment: Yes they have the same size, 16 * 16 * 16 (its a cube).

Comment: It can also be either. It's the chunk size for a video game but I can easily change the size to either be different dimentions or the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

You don't need to multiply matrices because you're just moving values around without changing them. All you have to do is map each input cell to its output cell.

#### Starting with 2D

Imagine you have a 3D array of 3x4x1. This can be represented by a 2D array of 3x4.

This is how each cell is associated when rotated:

```cs
// Rotating 90 degrees clockwise
output[i, j] = input[j, maxHeight - i];

// Rotating 90 degrees counter clockwise
output[i, j] = input[maxWidth - j, i];
```

(You can find the full code where these lines are used in context at the end of this post.)

#### Adding the 3rd dimension

Now instead of a 3x4x1, imagine we have a 3x4x2. That's equivalent to rotating two 2D arrays. Here's what the rotation code would look like.

```cs
// Rotating 90 degrees clockwise (around z axis)
output[i, j, k] = input[j, maxHeight - i, k];

// Rotating 90 degrees counter clockwise (around z axis)
output[i, j, k] = input[maxWidth - j, i, k];
```

From there, you can repeat the same pattern for rotating around the other axis.

```cs
// Rotating around the x axis (i doesn't change)
output[i, j, k] = input[i, maxHeight - k, j           ];
output[i, j, k] = input[i, k            , maxDepth - j];

// Rotating around the y axis (j doesn't change)
output[i, j, k] = input[maxWidth - k, j, i           ];
output[i, j, k] = input[k           , j, maxDepth - i];
```

#### Full code

The following code does the following:

1. It creates a 4x3 2D array and prints it.
2. It creates a new array by rotating the original array by 90 degrees clockwise and prints it.
3. It creates a new array by rotating the original array by 90 degrees counter-clockwise and prints it.

The code also contains a method called `Rotate90DegreesClockwiseAroundZAxis` that illustrates how to rotate a 3D array around the Z axis. You can use this code to generate the methods to rotate around the other axis.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] grid = new int[4, 3];

    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < grid.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            grid[i, j] = counter++;
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("Default:");
    PrintGrid(grid);

    var rotated90Grid = Rotate90DegreesClockwise(grid);
    Debug.WriteLine("Rotated 90:");
    PrintGrid(rotated90Grid);

    var rotated270Grid = Rotate90DegreesCounterClockwise(grid);
    Debug.WriteLine("Rotated 270:");
    PrintGrid(rotated270Grid);
}

static int[,] Rotate90DegreesClockwise(int[,] input)
{
    var inputWidth = input.GetLength(0);
    var inputHeight = input.GetLength(1);

    // We swap the sizes because rotating a 3x4 yields a 4x3.
    var output = new int[inputHeight, inputWidth];

    var maxHeight = inputHeight - 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < output.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < output.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            output[i, j] = input[j, maxHeight - i];
        }
    }

    return output;
}

static int[,] Rotate90DegreesCounterClockwise(int[,] input)
{
    var inputWidth = input.GetLength(0);
    var inputHeight = input.GetLength(1);

    // We swap the sizes because rotating a 3x4 yields a 4x3.
    var output = new int[inputHeight, inputWidth];

    var maxWidth = inputWidth - 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < output.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < output.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            output[i, j] = input[maxWidth - j, i];
        }
    }

    return output;
}

static int[,,] Rotate90DegreesClockwiseAroundZAxis(int[,,] input)
{
    var inputWidth = input.GetLength(0);
    var inputHeight = input.GetLength(1);
    var inputDepth = input.GetLength(1);

    // We swap the sizes because rotating a 3x4x5 yields a 4x3x5.
    var output = new int[inputHeight, inputWidth, inputDepth];

    var maxHeight = inputHeight - 1;

    for (int k = 0; k < inputDepth; k++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < output.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < output.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                output[i, j, k] = input[j, maxHeight - i, k];
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}

static void PrintGrid(int[,] grid)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < grid.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Debug.Write($"{grid[i, j]:D2} ");
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("---------------");
}
```

#### Output

```
Default:
00 01 02 03 
04 05 06 07 
08 09 10 11 
---------------
Rotated 90:
08 04 00 
09 05 01 
10 06 02 
11 07 03 
---------------
Rotated 270:
03 07 11 
02 06 10 
01 05 09 
00 04 08 
---------------
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for this! You just made my day! I can now continue onward with my game! This will be so much more performant than physically rotating an array! I really appreciate you helping me! I would upvote this if I could!